# Xcode 6.3 autocompletion slow with bridging header (e.g Parse)

Tags: xcode, swift, autocomplete

**tl:dr**

*Xcode Update 6.3.1 solved the problem for me.
It's still lightly slower than before but I'll give that shame to my Evo 840.*

**the problem**

Since I've installed the latest Xcode version (6.3) my projects with bridging headers seem to have problems with autocompletion. It's incredibly slow!

Is there any known workaround (except removing bridging headers...)?

EDIT:
Bug reports

```
20549109
20549764
20549768
```

EDIT (04/17/2015):

bugreport.apple.com marked this as a duplicate of

```
20445407
```

Comment: Ill never install this update :)

Comment: Well, it's working perfectly fine, except the autocompletion in combination with bridging headers...

Comment: Have you tried to restart xcode? Usually when autocompletion gets slow its because of SourceKitService, and by restarting that service it gets faster.

Comment: Does that problem produce with small swift files or big swift files?

Comment: It happens in either situation. Small files, big files. No difference (though I don't know what you'd expect to be big. Talking about ~2-3MB here). Restarting xCode doesn't resolve the problem. Removing the bridging header does. Though, that's not really an option :/

Comment: I filled up a bug report under number 20549109. Please do the same if you want to see this solved soon ;)) -> https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I will defenitely do that! :)

Comment: If you're managing big projects, and use a bridging header or will in the future, I would advise to stay out of this update. Keep the source kit crashes from the previous version, and stay away from the autocomplete problem. I also filled a bug report under 20549768.

Comment: Well, the problem here is that there are huge changes to swift which are not implemented in older versions. I'd like to be up to date, so I hope there will be a fix soon :D

Comment: Added the bug reports to the question.

Comment: This issue has been fixed for me as of Xcode 6.3.1. While the release notes for this version doesn't seem to mention the original support ticket (20445407 (Still open)), it seems to be working perfectly fine now.

Comment: I'll check and try that asap and update this thread!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Update 6.3.1 solved the problem for me! Thank you @nmdias!

Comment: What I do is, Preferences -> General -> Uncheck "Show live issues", "Continue building..." etc things.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues and after updating to xcode 6.3.1 and swift 1.2 they dissapeared.

Not appearing with xcode 7 & swift 2.0

Answer (score -1):

Steps are as:
1. Just go in user->Library->Developer->Xcode->DeriveData and delete the Data of folder(Derive data).
2. Just restart your system.
3. It will work better.